# Prevent button press state overlaying an imageview

Tags: android, button, imageview, overlay, pressed

I have the following button state

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ribbon_popular" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners_green"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                        android:textSize="22sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in code:

```
image.bringToFront();
ViewCompat.setElevation(image, 6);
```

which results in this view:
[image]

However when the button is pressed, it overlays the "POPULAR" badge like so:
[image]

I have tried adding the following code to try and bring the image forward when the button is in a pressed state, but it doesnt work for a press and hold state and only sometimes for a click event:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
                    motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_BUTTON_PRESS ||
                    motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_ENTER) {
               popularBadge.bringToFront();
               ViewCompat.setElevation(popularBadge, 12);
               parentLayout.invalidate();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any idea how i can make the image view always be above the button without having to use a FrameLayout?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Place imageview below button , i guess it will be fixed :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|start"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                         android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners_green"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                        android:textSize="22sp" />

                       <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ribbon_popular" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This answer is upon the property of `z-index`. If it solves do read about  it.

Comment: Hi Shubham, I have also tried that, and it doesn't work. I can't use z-index because im supporting devices pre lollipop, but i used `ViewCompat.setElevation(image, 6)` to set it higher, i'll update the question with this too

Comment: @davy307 : I have updated the answer . Add android:stateListAnimator="@null" to button and check.

Comment: that does indeed work, but it's not the desired effect, because now there is no animation on the button on click at all, what i want is for the badge to remain on top of the button throughout the click animation @shubham-srivastava

Comment: @davy307 : I guess this answers your original question, animation wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: you can see in the second image that the button is in a pressed state by the underlying shadow on it, so no, it doesnt answer the question sorry @shubham-srivastava